# Cómo puedo hacer para que al registrarme en un formulario no pase a la página php siguiente

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios, registro

Tengo este formulario de registro en html y he hecho la comprobación con php con mysqli_num_rows para que cuando se registre con un email que ya existe en la BD lo detecte y muestre un mensaje de que ese email ya existe. El caso es que la comprobación con la función que he creado en el fichero .php que recibe los datos del formulario funciona correctamente y muestra el mensaje si detecta que ese correo ya existe. Tal como lo tengo ahora tanto si se registra con un email que no existe como con uno que si existe pasa a la página de su registro se ha completado correctamente. La cosa es que quiero hacer que si detecta que el email introducido en el formulario ya existe al dar en el botón de registro, muestre el mensaje, pero se quede en la página del formulario sin pasar a la siguiente. No sé como plantearlo, si me pudierais echar una mano.

Este es el formulario de registro

```html
<form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Nombre -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Appellidos -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Ciudad -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required>
                            <label for="ciudad">CIUDAD</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Email -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="usuario@direccion.com" required maxlength="30">
                            <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<input type="submit" name="usub" value="¡QUIERO REGISTRARME!" id="boton-registro"/>
                
         </form>
```

Este es el fichero .php que recibe los datos y donde realizo la función que hace la comprobación

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');


$un = $_POST['nombre'];
$ua = $_POST['apellidos'];
$uf = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$ue = $_POST['email'];
$uc = $_POST['contrasena'];
$ut = $_POST['telefono'];
$uci = $_POST['ciudad'];

if(compruebaemail($ue)){
    echo "<div style='color:red'>Esta dirección de email ya está dada de alta </div>";
}else {
    $cnt = new UsuarioController();
    $ins = $cnt->crearUsuario($un, $ua, $uf, $ue, $uc, $ut, $uci);
}



function compruebaemail($ue){
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "BD");
    $sql="SELECT * from usuarios WHERE email='$ue'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
    
}

session_start();


?><html>

<head>
    <title>Registro completado</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Su registro se ha completado correctamente.<br> Se ha enviado un correo de confirmación a su cuenta.</h1>
        <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a>
    </div>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cuando dices al usuario que la dirección ya está dada de alta, no quieres que continúe la ejecución del script ¿no?

Comment: Exacto, quiero que muestre el mensaje pero no siga el proceso y se quede en la pantalla del formulario

Comment: En realidad lo que tiene que hacer el usuario no es quedarse donde está sino volver a donde estaba. Échale un ojo a esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

donde tienes el `return false;`

puedes remplazarlo con este `script`:

```
echo "<script> alert('El correo ya existe, por favor verifiquelo e intente de nuevo.');
    location.href = 'NOMBRE_DE_TU_PAGINA.php';
    </script>";
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó, es lo que quería. Muy amable!